# 400 Bad request on Firefox 45.0.1 and Safari 9.1

Tags: jquery, python, firefox, multipartform-data, forms, http-post

I am trying to submit form having a text and file field through jquery ajax and FormData. Its working fine on chrome but getting 400 Bad request on Firefox 45.0.1 and Safari 9.1. It was working fine on firefox 44 but the problem appeared once I updated it to 45.0.1. I have cleared everything including cache, cookies and history but still not working.

```
var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/slab/post/',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        $(".loader, .main-loader-overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

That's how my Request and Response Headers look like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Firefox and Safari doesn't send the **`filename`** attribute for the **`File Field`** if it is empty.
It can be seen clearly in the image below that the field name "post_photo" doesn't have any attribute filename.
[image]

As I am using Python Flask on the backend, it throws 400 Bad request if anything from the form is missing. 
So the only reason it was working on chrome was because it sends the **`filename`** attribute for the file field even if it is empty.
[image]

I used this `is_file_available = len(request.files.keys()) > 0` on backend to resolve my issue.